# Angular ssr : (click) from html is not working

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive, server-side-rendering

in my HTML i have simple click event that call to my typescript file.
This code is very simple for client side application however if I try the implement is SSR  this code is not working .
Not able run the any function from ui.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="accountnumber" [(ngModel)]="Order.accountnumber" value="">
    <button type="submit" (click)="executePython(Order)"> Continue >> </button>
    <button (click)="yourFunction()" >Test</button>
```

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Renderer2, ElementRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser ,isPlatformServer} from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

declare var brython: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contactus',
  templateUrl: './contactus.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contactus.component.css']
})
export class ContactusComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() Order = {
    accountnumber: ''

  };
  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
    private http: HttpClient) {
      isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    //throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    console.log("isPlatformBrowser: " + isPlatformBrowser)
    console.log("this.platformId: " + this.platformId)
    console.log("this.isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId): " + isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      // Code specific to the browser
      console.log('Running on the browser');
    }
    
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
       // Code specific to the server - like setting the title and tags
       console.log('Running on the server');
       console.log("this.platformId: " + this.platformId)
    }
  }


  pythonCode: string = '';
  pythonOutput: string = '';

  executePython(Order: any) {

    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
   

      this.pythonOutput = "hello";
    }

  }
  yourFunction() {

    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      alert("hello")
      
      this.pythonOutput = "hello";
    }

  }

}
```

This code is very simple for client side application however if I try the implement is SSR  this code is not working .

Comment: "This code is very simple for client side application", yet you have the function logic wrapped in a check to see if it's the server with no fallback

Comment: Angular is running in development mode.
platformId : server
is platformId : false <this is the output in console. wanted to add that my ssr application  is Working  as expected  however the   event from html is not working